# How to use AngularJS filter method with multiple check-boxes and regular input field?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I am new to AngularJS. I have a grid where I display all the list of customers with 5 different check boxes.

Such as FirstName, LastName, checkboxes are for Ribs/Chicken/Brisket etc.

I would like to use the AngularJS filter method.

Currently, I have the following search.FirstName, search.LastName

In the ng-repeat = customer in customers | filter: search

The question I have is that

How can I use the filter method with checkboxes?

Please help me out how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe if you save the value of the checkbox inside the search object model. I mean, I see you filter using a model call search, I don't how is the object data representation of your list, but I think maybe you have a property with possible values like `Ribs, Chicken, Brisket`

Comment: try using in the ng-model of each checkbox `ng-model = "search.nameOfProperty"`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Actually, I have resolved the issue by creating a custom filter for each category. So the displayed records can be filtered multiple ways.